# Efficient way to do constant method update in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got a countdown clock, which appears above an object in my game that has been planted/started to be built.

I'm using the Sparrow Framework.

Right now I'm just running a method in the onEnterFrame, that checks every frame (I've actually set it to every other frame but anyway) and updates the countdown clock, but I'm wondering if this is just a slow and inefficient way to do this.

Is there a way to update my counter, without it clogging things up?

I should add there will be a number of these countdown clocks on the game screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach would be to use a NSTimer that ticks at the same interval as you want your countdown counter to decrease at. Each tick you decrement the counter and call `setNeedsDisplay`.

If all you are doing is checking if the value of the countdown has changed `onEnterFrame`, and redrawing if the counter has changed, then you should be fine.

Comment: Hmm I'm just running it in the simulator right now, and I've got a tonne of stuff printing out in the console, and it just seems a little slow to me, which what got me wondering, would a NSTimer be any less processor intensive, or is it just a simulator issue?

Comment: Logging is somewhat resource intensive. If you are printing something out every `onEnterFrame` that is probably the cause of your slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

premature optimization.. you dont know its slow you think it might be

anyway, I dont follow. are you worried about drawing? if so. all view only do setNeedsDisplay and are refresh in batch mode every runloop iteration

Answer (score 0):

The least threads you run, the smoother it should go. A counter is merely a variable, it has a very minimal overhead, which you really shouldn't worry about.

Rendering operations, loading images, creating new objects, destroying objects and other things are far more resource consuming, so increasing a counter shouldn't be a performance worry at all.